# column "Serviços" is of type character varying[] but default expression is of type integer HINT: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression

Tags: python, django, django-models

My models:

```
class Orcamento(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    Cliente = models.CharField(max_length=40, default=0)
    Cod_Cliente= models.CharField(max_length=40, default=0)
    N_Orcamento = models.CharField(max_length=40, default=0)
    Endereço = models.CharField(max_length=50, default=0)
    Email = models.CharField(max_length=40, default=0)
    Telefone = models.CharField(max_length=40, default=0)
    Departamento = models.CharField(max_length=40, default=0)
    Data = models.CharField(max_length=40, default=0)
    Revisao = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    Serviços = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=100, default=[]))
                                            

    def __str__(self) -> str: #função para usar o nome do objeto e não a instância
        return self.Cliente
```

The error:

```
column "Serviços" is of type character varying[] but default expression is of type integer
HINT:  You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
```

How can I fiz this? I tried:

```
Serviços = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=100, default='empty'))
```

And doesn't work, same mistake.
Please help :/

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

always nice to find a fellow Brazilian here. :)

As far as I know, the `default` parameter should be part of the `ArrayField` invocation, not of `CharField`. Does the following work?

```
Serviços = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=100), default=list))
```

In case you still have problems after fixing the apparent mistake, it's usually due to older migrations having problems. In this case, you can delete all files in the `migrations` directory (except for `__init__.py`) and run `make migrations` and `migrate` again.

Comment: same error when I tryed migrate :/ 
And when I tryed makemigrations it works, but appears that: 
WARNINGS:
core.Orcamento.Serviços: (fields.E010) ArrayField default should be a callable instead of an instance so that it's not shared between all field instances.
        HINT: Use a callable instead, e.g., use `list` instead of `[]`.

Comment: That sounds like a stale migration problem. I'll update the answer to reflect what I *suspect* will fix the issue.

Comment: Now it works, thanks a lot <3

But do you know how to use in Django Admin? Just appear 1 collum "Serviços" and not an array

Comment: What you're defining is a column "Serviços" in which each item can be an array. Are you using a database  that allows array-valued fields (like PostgreSQL)?